# Select specific text of an HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, html

In the official docs about the method `Selection.addRange()` I can select the element when I have the specific range, but I don't know how to get the range for a specific word/target which is part of a text

Example:

```
<p>Hello world</p>
```

and I want to add the range selection for `world` like I would mark it manually with my mouse cursor.

Additionally: How can I select a specific text and mark it based on some Regex rules?

I couldn't find an answer on SO so far.
Official Mozilla docs about `addRange()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/addRange

Comment: What defines the word you want to select?

Comment: The word is any static string which is used to search the text and mark it. (Hopefully that's you have asked)

Comment: Search the text as in ctrl+f in the page?

Comment: Kinda, but it should select the range like in the link. Like you would drag your mouse cursor over a word

In Chrome `CTRL + F` just marks it yellow

Comment: How about adding a tag around the word you need to select, or create your own tag? https://jsfiddle.net/eamjw3qf/ or https://jsfiddle.net/6qgx1tzm/

Comment: Is there the possibility to make it dynamic?

Comment: There is another answer here which might help you: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works exactly for your example. The function retrieves the Text node from the given Element node, so mind that if the given element contains Element children (rather than direct text content) you have to adjust that function to your need.

```js
const el = document.getElementById('my-text-element');
selectWord(el, 'world');

function selectWord(element, word){
  const textNode = element.childNodes[0]; //retrieve the Text node from the Element node
  const selection = window.getSelection(); //get the Selection object
  const range = document.createRange(); //create the Range object
  const text = textNode.textContent; //retrieve the [string] from Text object
  const startPosition = text.search(word); //now we look for the word in the [string] value
  if(startPosition === -1) return; //if the word does not exist return and do nothing
  const endPosition = startPosition + word.length; //we need start and end position to select the found word
  range.setStart(textNode, startPosition); //it takes the Text node within we want to select some text, and we pass the starting character
  range.setEnd(textNode, endPosition); //we pass the ending character in the same Text node
  selection.addRange(range); //pass our prepared Range object and select the text
}
```

```html
<p id="my-text-element">hello world</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

To select a specific part of an element, that part should have its own tag that you can then select in the javascript

```
<p>Hello <span id = "xxx">world</span></p>
```

Comment: And without a tag like when I want to have it dynamic?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? Wouldn't the dynamic part be whatever you are doing in your javascript code with the selection?

Comment: If you just want to select an element which contains the text you are looking for, you could use jquery to dynamically select: $( "span:contains('world')" );